# list of neighboring points on a numberline of line segments?

Tags: algorithm

I have a numberline, 1 to 100.

Within the extents of that numberline, I can add and remove many line-segments.  These line-segments can intersect and overlap each other.

For a given x1 and x2, I need an efficient algorithm for iterating through all neighboring pairs of points (including x1 and x2) providing access to a list of all of the line-segments running between the neighboring points.

[image]

The results from this black numberline and the colored line-segments would be something like:

```
[0-20] -> []
[20-30] -> [red]
[30-40] -> [red, green]
[40-50] -> [green]
[50-60] -> []
[60-80] -> [purple]
[80-100] -> []
```

Comment: Is there a limit to the number of line segments that you are planning to have?

Comment: Any time-complexity requirements/restrictions?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight no, there is no limit, but in practice less than 10000

Comment: @DougRamsey just need it to be fast.  Caching data is a-okay.

Comment: Sounds like you need an interval tree http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree

Comment: Is the range of the line segments a given, and you merely want to find which points correspond to which line segments, or are you attempting to actually formulate the ranges of the line-segments themselves?  From what I can see with an interval tree, the ranges of the line-segments need to be given in order to construct the tree.

Comment: @Jason [colored] line segments are a given

Comment: All points there are integers, right?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight yes, all integers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use an [interval tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree).

Answer (score 0):

Create a list of boundary records, where each boundary is of the form

```
bound.type = start,finish
bound.position = 0..n
bound.color = red,green,blue...
```

and for each line segment add two such records to the list (ine for each end). Then sort all the records by position.
Now if you iterate through the list as follows:

```
colors=[]
write '[0'
for each bound in list
  write '-',bound.pos,'] -> [',colours,']'
  if bound.type = start then 
    add bound.color to colors
  else
    remove bound.type from colors
  write '[',bound.pos
write '-',n'] -> []'
```

you will have to do a little tidying up if the first line segment starts at 0 or if the last one ends at n.